# ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 0 and 512 when use of tensorflow 2.2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I try to run PFE model. It works well when I run eval_lfw with tensorflow 2.1 and tensorflow 1.x but when I tried to run it with tensorflow 2.2 and more I have this error :
ValueError: Node 'gradients/UncertaintyModule/fc_log_sigma_sq/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1_grad/FusedBatchNormGrad' has an _output_shapes attribute inconsistent with the GraphDef for output #3: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 0 and 512. Shapes are [0] and [512].
[It happens when the model is loading when it does saver = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(meta_file, clear_devices=True, import_scope=scope)  to import the meta file of my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaoay.png)

To reproduce the error : download https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10RnChjxtSAUc1lv7jbm3xkkmhFYyZrHP?usp=sharing
and run eval_lfw with parameters --model_dir pretrained/PFE_sphere64_msarcface_am --dataset_path data/Dataset --protocol_path ./proto/pairs_dataset.txt

Thank you for your help

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jordan/Bureau/Probabilistic-Face-Embeddings_new/evaluation/eval_lfw.py", line 78, in 
main(args)
File "/home/jordan/Bureau/Probabilistic-Face-Embeddings_new/evaluation/eval_lfw.py", line 51, in main
network.load_model(args.model_dir)
File "/home/jordan/Bureau/Probabilistic-Face-Embeddings_new/network.py", line 169, in load_model
saver = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(meta_file, clear_devices=True, import_scope=scope)
File "/home/jordan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1462, in import_meta_graph
**kwargs)[0]
File "/home/jordan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1486, in _import_meta_graph_with_return_elements
**kwargs))
File "/home/jordan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 799, in import_scoped_meta_graph_with_return_elements
return_elements=return_elements)
File "/home/jordan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jordan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 405, in import_graph_def
producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
File "/home/jordan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 501, in _import_graph_def_internal
raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Node 'gradients/UncertaintyModule/fc_log_sigma_sq/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1_grad/FusedBatchNormGrad' has an _output_shapes attribute inconsistent with the GraphDef for output #3: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 0 and 512. Shapes are [0] and [512].